# How do you chain a self-signed certificate to a root certificate?

Tags: windows, outlook, certificate, ms-office

I can create a self-signed digital certificate using Office's Selfcert.exe tool, but I don't know how to chain it to a root certificate.

Can someone tell me how to do it?

Comment: What do you mean "chained"? You mean trusted in the same way as a self-signed one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the self-signed certificate to inherit trust from a root certificate, that cannot be done.

The whole point of certificates is that the certificate authority (root certificate) has verified your identity in some non-electronic means, and is *issuing* a certificate to that effect.  So you cannot issue one yourself until you crack the root keys of the certificate authority - which is hopefully no small feat.